# C# XML - reading multiple elements at once

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<object>
    <name>Sphere</name>
    <material>Steel</material>
    <device Id="01">
        <model>Model 1</model>
        <color>Red</color>
    </device>
    <device Id="02">
        <model>Model 2</model>
        <color>Blue</color>
    </device>
</object>
```

I want to be able to read in a for loop both the model and the color of each device.
My code can only read only one value at a time (either model or value) and I have to go through the loop twice.

I expect there should be a more elegant solution.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\_Projects\AProjectsCS\XML_Tutorial\Sample.xml");

IEnumerable<XElement> list1 = xDoc.Root.Descendants("model");  
IEnumerable<XElement> list2 = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//color");  

foreach (XElement el in list1)
    Console.WriteLine(el.Value);

foreach (XElement el in list2)
    Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: So what is the problem with it?

Comment: I wanted to be able to read two elements at the same time (I have two loops foreach). The solution proposed by Sergey avoided that, having only one loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select both model and color elements values from each device element (you can use either anonymous type, as below, or create your custom `Device` class to hold this data):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\_Projects\AProjectsCS\XML_Tutorial\Sample.xml");
var devices = from d in xDoc.Root.Elements("device")
              select new {
                  Model = (string)d.Element("model"),
                  Color = (string)d.Element("color")
              };

foreach(var device in devices)
{
    Console.WriteLine(device.Model);
    Console.WriteLine(device.Color);
}
```

Comment: Lovely solution